# Eclipse, how to search variable occurrences inside the declaring scope

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclipse, how to search all the references to a variable inside the declaring scope? I want to navigate from variable declaration to the next expression using the variable, one by one, and jump to the final occurrence for convenience. Is this possible?

Text search wouldn't fit, as it is clunky if same variable name is used in other scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on variable and choose References -> Workspace

You will get all references to variable **only in scope**

Then you get arrow down/up to jump between occurrences

It seems you can't explicitly list the locations in the search result window (minimal grouped by method)

a workaround is to change name of variable to unique name and search for it

Comment: This only shows I have three matches in the method, but doesn't list the locations

Comment: Select your variable and press **Ctrl + Shift + G** as a shortcut for that.

Comment: You get arrow down/up to jump between occurrences

Comment: Is it possible to exclipitly list the locations in the search result window?

Comment: Not that I know of (Disclaimer: Intellij fan)

Comment: a workaround is to change name of variable to unique name and search for it

Answer (score 1):

- You can find declarations of your variable with **Ctrl + Shift + G**. Be sure that you choose your variable.
- Or you can find it from right click -> References or Declarations